# why insert query is not working in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, laravel-5, sql-insert

I am new to Laravel 5 and MVC. I can not figure out why is my INSERT query not running but JUST directing me to search page. below is my code.

edit: the database connection is  proper and I can view data on page via same database

```html
public function insert()
{

DB::table('patients')->insert(
array('name' => 'fakhir', 'email' => 'hello@email.com')

  );
return view('patients/search');
}
```

Comment: What does insert() return?

Comment: insert function just moves me to the Search view.   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try '->where', let me know what you get.

```
public function insert()
{

DB::table('patients')->where('#')->insert(
array('name' => 'fakhir', 'email' => 'hello@email.com')

  );

return view('patients/search');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to adding with eloquent ? I think firstly, You should try to adding with eloquent. 
You test it in this way

```
Patients::create(['name'=>'fakhir','email'=>'hello@email.com']);
```